How to install Canon MP270 Inkjet printer on Ubuntu 24.04
I had the Canon MP270 Inkjet printer working on Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 23.10, but I'm stuck installing it on Ubuntu 24.04.

It turns out adding the printer-driver-gutenprint package adds in a cups driver for the MP270 that works on 24.04
